# Java Thread loops running sequentially

Tags: java

```
public class Meh {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread th2=new Thread() { 
            public void run(){
                for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
                    System.out.println("No 2 "+i);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread th1=new Thread() { 
            public void run(){
                for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
                    System.out.println("No 1 "+i);
                }
            }
        };

        for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            System.out.println("main "+i);
        }
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

Why are my loops running sequentially?The three loops get interchanged but inside the loop they run sequentially. I can't figure it out why? I am a beginner in java.

Comment: Take a look on how to implement a Runnable and Callable thread attempt.
Cool nickname by the way ;)

Comment: Additionally, please take the time to format your code readably. At the moment the indentation is poor and there are lots of sequences of blank lines for no reason. When writing the question, use the preview and ask yourself whether that's the way you'd want to see the code if you were trying to answer the question.

Comment: Context switching between threads is relatively costly, so it is not done too often when not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Black_jack. You there? :)

Comment: Your code formatting is not good, especially your code indentation. Understand that code formatting isn't there to make code "look good" but rather the rules are there to help you quickly see what code belongs to what scope, something that helps you debug and understand your code. You will want to put in the effort to format well, for *your* benefit, so you can more easily debug problems, and for *ours* so we can more easily understand your code and help you. I've fixed your code for you this time, but in the future this should be the asker's responsibility.

Comment: Try starting your threads **before** the `for` loop in `main` method.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be anything but sequential?

Comment: @Henry Context switching? I don't think they sell computers anymore with a single CPU core - there is as much change that the two threads run on separate cores and do not context switch between each other as that they do context switch.

Answer (score 2):

## Why does your code run sequentially

Your code has 3 parts, which I have colour coded as follows:

### Red

```
 Thread th1 = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
         for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
             System.out.println("No 1 " + i);
         }
     }
 };
```

...

```
for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
    System.out.println("main "+i);
}
th1.start();
th2.start();
```

### Green

```
Thread th1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("No 1 " + i);
        }
    }
};
```

### Blue

```
Thread th2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("No 2 " + i);
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, green and blue will mix together, but they will not run out of their own order, (No 1 6 will never happen before No 1 5, but could be anywhere compared to the No 2 items).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have misunderstood what a Thread actually does. Putting loops inside a Runnable doesn't automatically parallelize them for you. It just runs the code sequentially but in a separate thread. I'm guessing what you really want is the following:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[11];

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    threads[i].setName("Thread #"+i);
}

for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.start();
}
```